# Excel - Get the last cell in a 1D range that is not equal to some value

Tags: excel, excel-2007, worksheet-function, excel-2010

Without using VBA (pure formula solution), is there a way to get the last cell in a 1-dimensional range that is not equal to some value?  For example:

```
        A
1       Bob
2       Bob
3       Bob
4       Jane
5       Sam
```

Applying logical over A1:A5 and excluding "Bob" would return "Sam"

Comment: interesting question - but what should happen if all values are "Bob"?

Comment: @Juliusz - good catch on corner case...it should return blank or empty string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Enter it as an array formula by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

```
=INDIRECT("A" & MAX(IF(A1:A5<>"Bob",ROW(A1:A5))))
```

Comment: thanks!  good solution. I can work out the corner case mentioned by Juliusz